# How to select indices using a combination of loc and iloc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a time-sorted dataset indexed by dates looking like:

```
             result
2009-09-08  Positive
2009-08-24  Negative
2009-06-01  Positive
2009-04-23  Positive
2008-12-06  Positive
 ...         ...
```

I would like to find a date, for example, 2009-08-24 plus the two rows below the date, i.e.

```
2009-08-24  Negative
2009-06-01  Positive
2009-04-23  Positive
```

My problem is that finding a specific date requires loc (df.loc['2009-08-24']), but finding that date and two rows below requires numerical position (iloc). In matlab, I would first find the numerical row number 'n' of '2009-08-24' (the second row in this case) and then select rows 'n' to 'n + 2'. But I am not sure if there is an easier way in python. Thansk!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
df.loc['2009-08-24':].head(2)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`df.index.get_loc('2009-08-24')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) will return the 'numerical row number' for the date you want.